# Does Cypress really scroll to the given element while clicking on it?

Tags: javascript, cypress, autotest

Cypress declares that before performing `dblclick()` command and other actions it makes the command subject visible by means of scrolling to it. But I have a problem with this. In my test I have a chain of the commands:

```
cy.get(...).find(...).find(...).dblclick()
```

And if the element is outside the visible part of the screen, it is not clicked. If I use cy.wait(5000) before the chain of the commands and scroll the screen manually within those 5 sec. the dblclick() succeeds. So the question is do they really make scrolling?

Comment: Yes it does scroll.

I'm curious, did you receive any warning by Cypress? And what does that warning say? I noticed that Cypress sometimes has issues to click a button and that adding the option `{force: true}` solves that problem.

Comment: Yes I got the message that the element or one of its parent is not visible. Yes I had tried force: true, but it did not work.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to figure this out?